# Why cv2.threshold has to have 2 argument (ret, thresh)?

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, image-processing

Simple question

what is ret?

I know that thresh is the result of numpy array after thresholding an image
but what is the function of ret ?
(I only know ret is the constant but still don't know how to get this value and how it works)

Thank you for the answer
even it's such an idiot answer for expert

Comment: if im sure, it must have 4 arguments in total (image_src, thresholdValue, maxVal, thresholdingTechnique)

Answer (score 2):

This page have a very detailed explanation:

https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html

Search for `retval` gives you the following:
Then the algorithm finds the optimal threshold value and returns you as the second output, `retVal`. If Otsu thresholding is not used, `retVal` is same as the threshold value you used.

Answer (score 1):

I quote from this [link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2021/04/28/opencv-thresholding-cv2-threshold/#:%7E:text=We%20use%20the%20cv2.,T%2C%20is%20the%20threshold%20value)
That said:

> The cv2.threshold function then returns a tuple of 2 values: the first, T, is
> the threshold value. In the case of simple thresholding, this value is
> trivial since we manually supplied the value of T in the first place. But in
> the case of Otsu’s thresholding where T is dynamically computed for us, it’s
> nice to have that value. The second returned value is the thresholded image itself.

What you mean by `ret` is the T from above explanation.

Comment: instead of some random website, you could have quoted the official documentation. that's what the writer of that blog did (he paraphrased so he didn't have to cite where he got that info from)